# Is there a term for this kind of eccentrically threaded fastener or washer that has wrench flats and curved faces

Tags: terminology, fasteners

Is there a standard term for this fastener or for the kind of problem it is intended to address?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a form of slot nut, perhaps for use in a metal panel with slots to allow some adjustment of the nut in the slot. I can't find anything like it on an image search. Where did you find the image?

Comment: Looks like a custom-made [flange nut](https://www.google.com/search?q=flange+nut&rlz), but not exactly. It could perhaps be intended for a T-slot per previous comment, although those often have a thicker "flange" part, and are more rectangular. The eccentric feature and carefully made circular flange suggests a cam action.

Comment: I was searching for something eccentric that could serve as a kind of  miniature cam and it came back in the internet search results. It's some kind of part used by food service equipment. `Alto Shaam WS-25124 Washer Ct Eccentric Ml Blocks`